# Spring Boot redirecting POST in context path

Tags: java, spring-boot

The application return redirect (302) when i make a POST in base context path, and i get a error.

My `application.properties`

```
...
server.servlet.context-path=/api/v1/application
...
```

My controler

```
@RestController
public class RestService {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseDTO myMethod(@RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO) {
        log.trace("m=myMethod");
        return service.insert(requestDTO);
    }

}
```

If I make POST in http://localhost:8080/api/v1/application
I get a Redirect 302 to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/application/ and if the client follow redirect the application return 405 (method not allowed)

Curl

```
C:\>curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/customer HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302
< Location: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2020 23:34:07 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: try to change to @PostMapping("/")

Comment: there is a requestbody parameter .. did you hit api using postman ?

Comment: I already try this, but not work.